# How to get text and line in a straight line in html

Tags: html, css

How can I get a line, text and then a line in a straight line?

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/vinayawsm/9MLpJ/2/). Here is the jsfiddle of my html. I use inline property to make them appear in a straight line. But they do not change.

How to do so that they appear like

```
---------------------- About Me ---------------------
(^^dotted line above should actually be single line.)
```

Comment: Where is the line in the Fiddle?

Comment: sorry I shared a wrong link.. I updated it now

Comment: Can't you use `table` with 3 `td` inside single `tr`?

Comment: Try using `:before` and `:after` instead of `hr` for a simpler HTML code with full customization http://jsfiddle.net/9MLpJ/9/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this -

```
#about_me1 hr, #about_me1 h3{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Here's updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9MLpJ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and have a look to `display:inline-block` in `style`

```
<header id="about_me">
    <div id="about_me1">
    <hr size="5" align="left" color="black" style="display:inline-block;width:30%;">
    <h3 style="display:inline;">About Me</h3>
    <hr id = "line" size="5" align="left" width="30%" color="black" style="display:inline-block;width:30%;">
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only one element to show border, which will work in every resolution and reusable:

```
<header id="about_me">
    <div id="about_me1">
         <h3><span>About Me</span></h3>

    </div>
</header>


#about_me1 {
    border-top: 2px solid #FF0000;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:15px;
}
h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px;
}
h3 span {
    background:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9MLpJ/7/)